# Is it possible to get PHPmailer to send the mail after the page loads?

Tags: javascript, php, phpmailer

I have a script that sends at least one Email using PHPMailer, but potentially up to 5.
The action of sending the mail delays the page loading by around 2-3 seconds.
This would almost be acceptable, but obviously this doubles and triples for each extra Email sent.
Even placing the code after the page HTML doesn't make a difference.
I know PHP is apparently a "single thread" application, but surely there's a smarter way of doing this?  Is there some fancy javascript applet that will silently load another page in the background, or is there a neater way?
Any tips welcomed.

Comment: What's the problem? You can load a library on demand. Just wrap its loading in a function.

Comment: You could always write some javascript fired by the page the user see's. This js can just launch a php script run on the server that does the emailing. You woudl need to be a little clever processing errors but that would stop the page script from having to do the 1-5 emails as part of its processing.

Comment: Use some kind of queue to store outgoing emails and a worker e.g. launched by a cron-job that processes a certain amount of mails in a specified amount of time.

Comment: Scorpion: It makes no difference, the page still processes the script before loading even if called via a function.  RiggsFolly - thanks, I used the javascript load method in the end (I'll post an answer).  Nietonfir - thanks, though would prefer to keep it "native" to PHP without external server processes etc.

Comment: I suggest Gearman. Just dispatch a job and it will run async.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea why anyone modded this post down as it's a perfectly valid question, but for anyone's future reference, I got around it by embedding the page with jquery/ajax, as below:

```
<div id="contentext"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#contentext").load("sendmail.php");
});
</script>
```

This way the page loads immediately, kicks off the sendmail script, and also outputs the result/errors from PHPmailer etc.

Thanks for the other suggestions though: The exec method is good to know, as is the cron job to periodically process scripts option, however, I prefer this method as it keeps things within the native PHP/Javascript environment without calling on external processes via the OS etc.

Answer (score 0):

I usually write a separate script that accepts the necessary data as command line arguments and then launch that script as a background process so that the main script can exit without waiting for it to finish. Like so:

```
exec("nohup /usr/bin/php mailerscript.php $param1 $param2 > /dev/null &");
```

Inside mailerscript.php, you can access `$param1` and `$param2` as `$argv[1]` and `$argv[2]`. Make sure mailerscript.php is executable to the webserver process and that you specify the full path to it in your exec.

Comment: Thanks, it's really useful to know of that method for future reference, though I opted for the embedded javascript option in the end.

Comment: @BSUK You're welcome. I think the question is perfectly valid. Don't let the downvotes get you down. As an aside, I use the server-side method because I am working in the context of a web service. So the clients that connect usually are not browsers and do not have access to javascript.